# Pass parameter to tab

Tags: angularjs

I am building my first Angular app with a list of product specifications such as "Brand name" etc. The finished app will be connected to an MSSQL db.

I have a list with the saved Specifications and when I click one of them I want the following to happen:

1. Show Edit Specification Tab
2. Pass the parameter SpecificationId
3. Perform an http GET with current Specification Id

I set up a plunker with the app in its basic state:

http://embed.plnkr.co/4F8LMwMorZEF0a42SzTJ/

Comment: And what is your **question** now?

Answer (score 0):

As you are already sending your id you just need to get it within your method:

Update your controller like this:

```
app.controller('TabController', function ($scope) { // use $scope here
```

and set the id in the `$scope.spec` object like below:

```
this.setTab = function (selectedTab, specId) { // get the id in the args here
     this.tab = selectedTab;
     $scope.spec = {id : specId}; // set the id in here
     console.log($scope.spec.id);
};
```

and then you can bind the id value in the markup as this:

```
The current Specification ID is: <strong>{{spec.id}}</strong>
```

### [Updated plunkr demo.](http://plnkr.co/edit/MrCjxcahGUMkCdVISslN?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! How do I use the ID in the EditSpecController and pass it as a condition in a http get to fetch the data that belongs to that Specification ID? If the ID is undefined or = 0 I want it to clear the form input and set an input type hidden with the current ID so I can tell the script I am posting the editSpecForm to whether it is an update of a current item or if it is a new one.

Comment: @user2750754 Then you can create a factory for this to share data.

Comment: Okay. Still haven't really got it when it comes to Angular so it is a struggle. Is it possible for you to give a brief example or some pointers? An important part here is also that the action takes place when the tab is activated. The ID will also not always be a Specification Id it might be a Product Id on the product tab as well. Appreciate your help!